# How to enable the clipboard function in vim?

Tags: linux, vim, gentoo

Environment:

1. Gentoo
2. vim 7.3

I have search in Google and find the way:

`vim --version | grep clipboard`

and find that my vim doesn't open the clipboard support

To open the clipboard and xterm_clipboard support in vim.

I add these use flags in package.use:

`app-editors/vim clipboard xterm_clipboard`

but I use `equery -q uses app-editors/vim`, but nothing add。

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is the output of `vim --version | grep clipboard`? A `-` in front of `clipboard` and/or `xterm_clipboard` means that your Vim is not compiled with clipboard support. If that's the case, get another version like `vim-gnome` (or something like that, YMMV) which supports clipboard.

Comment: I am not install the X-window, and use putty to login in

Comment: Clipboard is dependent on X: no X, no clipboard. [You can use xclip](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/GNU/Linux_clipboard_copy/paste_with_xclip) as an alternative, though. But… that will work only on the remote machine. Do you want to copy locally and paste remotely with `p`? Or copy remotely with `y` and paste locally? That's not possible without rolling up your sleeves.

Comment: @romainl How do you imagine `xclip` being an “alternative” if you don’t have X?

Comment: Because I'm stupid. Thanks for pointing it out.